# Whats wrong with my Thymeleaf form

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

Trying to create a form in thyme leaf but I keep getting the error message below:

Error during execution of processor 'org.thymeleaf.spring4.processor.attr.SpringInputGeneralFieldAttrProcessor' (customer-form:19)

Here is my Thymeleaf template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <title>Save Customer</title>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"/>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="add-customer-style.css"/>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="header">
            <h2>Customer Relationship Manager</h2>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="container">
        <h3>Save Customer</h3>
        <form action="saveCustomer" th:object="${customer}" method="post"/>
        <table>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td><label>First Name</label></td>
                    <td><input type="text" th:field="*{firstName}"/></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

and the controller that holds it:

```
@Controller
public class CustomerController {

    private ServiceDAO serviceDAO;

    @Autowired
    public void setServiceDAO(ServiceDAO serviceDAO) {
        this.serviceDAO = serviceDAO;
    }

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String listCustomers(Model model){

        List<Customer> customers = serviceDAO.findAll();
        model.addAttribute("customers", customers);
        return "home";
    }

    @GetMapping("/ShowFormForAdd")
    public String ShowFormForAdd(Model model){

        Customer customer = new Customer();

        model.addAttribute("customer", customer);

        return "customer-form";
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you close your form tag after your input fields.  Second, update your action to have Thymeleaf resolve it properly:

```
  <form th:action="@{/saveCustomer}" th:object="${customer}" method="post">
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td><label>First Name</label></td>
                <td><input type="text" th:field="*{firstName}"/></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
  </form>
```

Comment: If that worked, just mark it with a checkmark and/or upvote.